# Converting between timezones

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I know of several ways to do this, and a lot of them use DateTime class objects.  I am storing timestamps in a database using:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Phoenix");
$time=time();
$timezone='America/Chicago';
//$time and $timezone are then stored accordingly.
```

Then I can retrieve the time in my timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Phoenix");
echo date("m/d/Y g:i:s a",$time);
//or if I want to display it to the user:
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
echo date("m/d/Y g:i:s a",$time);
```

My question is, is it appropriate to manipulate PHP's timezone like this to achieve a sense of locality when it comes to displaying dates and times, or should I be using one of the packaged objects to handle this?

Comment: How about starting using [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime)?

Comment: But why?  Is there a reason I should?

Comment: Primarily because it handles all of this for you, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Tim Withers: it gives handy tools to manipulate with dates, without changing *global application-wide* timezone setting

Comment: PS: what DB do you use? Cannot it convert to required TZ itself?

Comment: @zerkms - I am using mysql, but its scheduling scripts, so the user signs up on a schedule.  I always need it to be in 'America/Phoenix', but when I make updates and/or send out a reminder, I want to display it their time.

Comment: @zerkms - I have it written all this using DateTime, but came decided to write a test script to see if the above would work, and indeed it does.  That's pretty much why I was wondering if it was an acceptable practice.

Comment: @Tim Withers: any solution that changes some global state and relies on that state after is barely acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the php's built in [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object family to handle this. You can do timezone conversions with it pretty easy:

```
 // assuming the data coming from the database and it's in the America/Phoenix timezone
 $localtime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $db_date_string, new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'));
 $chicago_time = $localtime;
 $chicago_time->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
 print $chicago_time->format('m/d/Y g:i:s a');
```

This keeps the timezone manipulation in a tightest scope possible (one datetime only).

Also i would recommend to store database data in only one timezone and converting it in the application just before display/use. This could save you a tons confusion at debugging. (It could have saved me at least :-P)